# 'Fool' Team Foundation Server into adding files under previous source control

Tags: tfs, migration, tfs-2015, tfs-2010

I have my program code under TFS 2010 Source Control. TFS is running on a Windows 7 (32 bit) machine. The database server for the TFS is SQL 2008 (NOT SQL Server Express). I'm the only person using TFS.

I'm trying to set up TFS on my new Windows 2010 Professional machine. I don't want to spend the almost $1000 it would cost me to use TFS 2018 backed with the cheapest version of SQL Server that would be compatible.

So, I have installed TFS 2015 Express, which created a SQL Server Express database. I tried 'replacing' the SQL Express databases created by the installation with my SQL Server 2008 databases. Did not work.

I'm trying to 'upload' my files from my projects using the Add Items to Folder button. I was able, by renaming the vssscc and vspscc files in the project directories and was able to upload the folders under the root directory for the project. But, I cannot add the vast majority of the files at the root of the project.

So, I'm stumped. I know in Source Safe, there was a simple way to 'fool' Source Safe into letting you use the Add Files to re-add files that were under source control. If there's a way to do this with TFS, I would be fine using that, I don't have that many projects to upload. Or, if there is another way I can get my code files back under TFS Source Control, I would like to know how to do that.

Comment: If you don't have a budget for upgrading and maintaining TFS, consider using Azure DevOps, which is the modern, cloud-hosted version of TFS. It's largely free for basic capabilities, and if you're currently using TFS 2010, the stuff you'd have to pay for is probably going to be something you're not using today because **it didn't exist 11 years ago**.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you should reference to the following Microsoft Docs to migrate the data from your TFS 2010 to TFS 2015:

- [**Upgrade Azure DevOps Server**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=tfs-2015)
- [**Requirements for Azure DevOps on-premises**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=tfs-2015)

Normally, you need to upgrade your TFS 2010 to TFS 2013 latest version at first, then upgrade from TFS 2013 to RFS 2015.

In addition, what do you mean "**`Windows 2010 Professional` machine**"? I do not find any released Windows server OS is named this. And also do find any TFS version supports this OS. Can you share more details about the OS?